# Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD, virtualization is turned on

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

recently installed android studio on my pc, created virtual device but when I click " run 'app' " the only thing that happens is error "Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD", this error is in "Run" tool window, besides that there's absolutely no information what and why that happens.

Few things worth mentioning:

```
I have enabled virtualization in bios
I tried deleting virtual device and create new one, no change
I have installed android sdk
```

Anyone knows how to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check AVD Manager if there is no permission denied for /dev/kvm. If it is the issue, open the terminal in Android Studio and run `sudo chmod 777 /dev/kvm` and it will solve your problem.

Better solution is change the ownership of /dev/kvm from root to the owner of current app by running the command `sudo chown -R "your account name" /dev/kvm`.

Comment: Linux Mint, 2022: after rebooting to enable virtualization in the bios, it still wouldn't work, but `chmod 777 /dev/kvm` did - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just had to **install the proper drivers for** my **graphics card**. I was using the Ubuntu's default, *nouveau*.

Answer (score 0):

for people who are having this problem now in 2021, try to disable the vanguard anti cheat of valorant..he has been having some compatibility problems with android Studio.

Comment: Are you sure this workaround is for the same symptom? From some other answers it looks like Vanguard causes an "Incompatible software detected" error (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65727835/2833126)

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Studio Arctic Fox patch 4, I resolved the issue by adding a new virtual device (for the simulator) which was for ARM architecture.
Here are details with screenshots about the steps on [ConfessionsOfAnAgileCoach](https://confessionsofanagilecoach.blogspot.com/2021/12/androidstudio-development-with-m1-mac.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. it might help.

AVD Manager

1. your current running device's option
2. Show On Disk // it will open some folders and files.
3. Delete all .lock folders.
4. Then run.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

open your AVD folder from here
[Screenshort of the folder option (click) to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ5Uv.png)and Delete the 'hardware-qemu.ini.lock' folder and 'your_Project_name.lock' file and close the Android studio,
then re-launch the studio.
It will work.