# Android Studio - Vanguard detected (Incompatible Software detected) while it's not even installed or opened as a process

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio worked properly yesterday,today I started the android studio and all of a sudden it throws the "Incompatible software detected" and i dont have the "Riot Vanguard" installed, deleted it a while ago and I double checked to locate installation and I couldn't find a thing.
How come it still pops out even after the Android studio worked properly?

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is a month old, but I thought I'd share some help for those coming from Google.

This error pops up because Riot Vanguard (which is known for causing some issues with the emulator) is installed. Riot Vanguard is an anti-cheat system installed along Valorant. So, you have several options:

**Keep everything as is**

If you dismiss the alert and your emulator works as expected, then you're good to go. I've been developing for Android for a year now with Vanguard installed, without any issues.

**Disable the Vanguard service**

If something doesn't work as expected, and you don't want to uninstall Valorant, then your next option would be to disable the Vanguard service. For this, you can either go into the **Services** manager of Windows, or disable it directly from the console. To do the latter, open an elevated CMD and type:

```
sc config vgc start= disabled
```

Then, restart your PC, and you're good to go.

This, however, will prevent you from playing Valorant. If you'd like to play, you need to enable Vanguard again, with the following command, and restarting your PC afterwards:

```
sc config vgc start= system
```

**Uninstall Vanguard**

Last option is to uninstall both Valorant and Riot Vanguard. Make sure the Riot Vanguard service is deleted too. You might find it in C:\Program Files\Riot Vanguard\vgc.exe